# Disable window.onbeforeunload and window.onunload in XULRunner

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

I am developing a XULRunner application that does some processing on web sites. As I plan to make the whole process automated, I am trying to figure out how to cope with sites that utilize the `window.onunload` and `window.onbeforeunload` events.

I disabled the use of alert/prompt/confirm using:

```
pref("capability.policy.default.Window.alert", "noAccess");
pref("capability.policy.default.Window.confirm", "noAccess");
pref("capability.policy.default.Window.prompt", "noAccess");
```

I also tried to set `window.onunload` and `window.onbeforeunload` before and after calling `browser.loadURI`. That did not work. How can I disable these events?

Answer (score 0):

Use addEventListener to disable beforeunload:

```
browser.contentWindow.addEventListener(‘beforeunload’, function(e){ return false; }, true);
```

Unload [cannot be prevented](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html), otherwise the user would be trapped.